# MVC View calls js function on page load. But before js function is rendered, page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Here is the Action metod ilan:

```
public ActionResult Ilan()
{
   ...
   return View();
}
```

Below is the view "ilan" which has a form and a jquery returning the "openBoxOpen" function which displays the page in a popup window instead of the browser. Form is posting to another action method called "Cody" which you can see further down.

```
<script type="text/javascript">                                  
    $(function () { return ibFunc.openBoxOpen('/giris/ilan'); });
</script>

<form action="/giris/Cody" method="post">  
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.sirketler)
    {
       <input type="radio" name="ad" id="optionsRadios1" value="@item.Value" checked="checked"/> @item.Text<br />
    }
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" onclick="return foo();" value ="GİRİŞ"/>
</form>
```

Here is the action method the form above posts the radiobutton's value:

```
[HttpPost]
[ViewException]
public ActionResult Cody(int ad)
{
    ....
    return View("ilan");
}
```

It's working. But what happens is, page is first displayed in a second on the browser and then pop up appears. How to prevent the browser displaying the page is the question.

First, page's loaded normally:

[image]

And next, the pop up loads:

[image]

I want the popup to be displayed only.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it happens (seems like bug is hard to reproduce), but try to start finding this bug with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">                                  
    $(function () {
        setTimeout(function() {
            ibFunc.openBoxOpen('/giris/ilan');
        }, 1000);
    });
</script>
```

Tell if it helps.

Comment: Page still comes up first and then Window starts popping up every second. Total 7 times

Comment: Wow, 7 times! I can definitely say that the problem is not with the code you posted!